how to update timer every second in Tkinter label for chess GUI?
I have made a simple chess GUI with tkinter. Now I want to add a clock for each player.
The clock is displayed in a label's text. It works in human player's turn. The time changes every second. When in chess engine's turn, the time only updates after engine finishing computation, not every second anymore.
The update code is as following:
self.player_one_timer_label.config(text=time_str)
self.player_one_timer_label.after(1000, self.update_timer) 

how to update the timer every second when chess engine computing? Thanks.

That's exactly how you should do it, you just need to run the engine computation in a separate thread or process, so that it doesn't block Tkinter's event loop.

Thanks. Could you recommend some documentations about how to do it? I am using python chess library.

What does str do? text=str.  Don't use str . It is valid for Python.

I edit it. It it a string to set time
